# Visual Studio Code: Find empty files

Tags: visual-studio-code, find, is-empty

Is there a way to find all empty files (with vscode) in a project?
I try to open all my .scss files, and already installed 'search - open all results', however even with regEx I wasn't able to find them all because some of them are empty.

Also I just discoverd, that this extension only opens the first 10 matches (regardless if in the same file or not) - so a more handy solution would be preferable.

Comment: Did you find any solution? I would appreciate it.

Comment: not so far - worked around then. sry

..however giving it another thought.. what about an empty regex? i mean.. it is line/stream based, but wouldn't do sth. like this the trick:

`(?!\n|.|\r|\Z)`
(..not tested..)

Comment: I did something easy. Went to the explorer where project is located, searched in window search like .css  size:empty. In my case, I wanted to find all css files which are empty.

Comment: yeah - however the topic here is to do that _within_ vsc... there are plenty other ways

Comment: This regex seems to work in vscode: `(?<!\s)(^$)(?!\n)` if by empty you mean one line with nothing on it.  And not even one `newline`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This regex would allow you to find empty files `^$(?<!\n)(?!\n)`. It's basically saying, find all empty lines that are not preceded by or followed by a new line.

Comment: Bit dated, but i recall vaguely winding up with a similar solution, using negative lookarounds (inspired by @Mark ´s respond). Therefore (and to close this thread ;) I’ll mark this as appropriate answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

You could open a terminal in vscode and run `find . -empty`

Comment: `find . -empty -type f` if you want to find only empty files (not folders)